# Can I get mobile name from cordova device uuid?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, mobile-development

I want to reverse engineer on cordova device uuid.

How do I get the device name from the device uuid?

Comment: you want a device model for installed apk right.

Comment: @Sathiyaraj yes, I want device model.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must install the apk in your device. 
After that, simply use this:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/1.6.0/cordova/device/device.uuid.html

Also, have a look at this:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova/device/device.html

Comment: It is not given in the documentation.